# How to replace \n with comma and remove the last \n ? - iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display text which return from server in a label. Server return something like this `*English\nMalay\nTamil\n*`.

Currently I use:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@", "
```

to replace the `\n` with comma. But how do I remove the last `\n`?

Now my text in the label shows:

> "English, Malay, Tamil,"

I would like to get like

> "English, Malay, Tamil"

Comment: after replacement check last character if last  character is "," remove last character

Comment: why not remove last \n by using substring?

Comment: check my answer... no need to convert to array and re-convert to string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this way.

```
NSString *string =  @"English\nMalay\nTamil\n";
//Make array from string
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
//Remove all empty object from array
[array removeObject:@""];
//Join array object and make string
NSString *newString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Comment: @Winter Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below code

```
NSString *string=@"English\nMalay\nTamil\n";

NSMutableArray *arryLanguagge = [[string componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"] mutableCopy];

 [arryLanguagge removeObject:@""];

NSString *strLanguaage=[arryLanguagge componentsJoinedByString:@","];

NSLog(@"%@",strLanguaage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove last `\n` before making replacement by using `substringToIndex`?

```
NSString *mString =  @"English\nMalay\nTamil\n";
NSLog(@"mString===before===%@", mString);
mString = [mString substringToIndex:mString.length-1];
mString = [mString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@", "];
NSLog(@"mString===after===%@", mString);
```

Output

```
mString===before===English
Malay
Tamil

mString===after===English, Malay, Tamil
```